# Wait for Dropdown to Populate / Load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select, webdriverwait

This is a section of my current Python script:

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleYear")).select_by_visible_text("2015")
time.sleep(4)
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleMake")).select_by_visible_text("HONDA")
time.sleep(4)
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleModel")).select_by_visible_text("CIVIC 4D LX")
```

I want to get rid of `time.sleep(4)` and use `WebDriverWait` instead. I use `WebDriverWait` extensively, but never where I need to wait until the list populates. I've tried many combinations, but none of them work.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
    vehicleYear = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleYear"))))
    vehicleYear.select_by_visible_text("2015")
    vehicleMake = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleMake"))))
    vehicleMake.select_by_visible_text("HONDA")
    vehicleModel= Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleModel"))))
    vehicleModel.select_by_visible_text("CIVIC 4D LX")
```

Here is the exception message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\Box Sync\Documents\GitHub\appd-selenium-scripts\Digital_FFQ_PROD_Auto_Synthetic_Script.py", line 169, in <module>
    vehicleMake.select_by_visible_text("HONDA")
  File "C:\Users\uswarv41\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 140, in select_by_visible_text
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: HONDA


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 265, in main
    wait=args.wait)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 256, in handle_args
    run_main(addr, name, kind, *extra, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_local.py", line 52, in run_main
    runner(addr, name, kind == 'module', *extra, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\runner.py", line 32, in run
    set_trace=False)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1283, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1290, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\Box Sync\Documents\GitHub\appd-selenium-scripts\Digital_FFQ_PROD_Auto_Synthetic_Script.py", line 181, in <module>
```

I believe I have resolved by issue. Created the following function:

```
def loop_select_keys(eName, eValue):
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            return Select(driver.find_element_by_id(eName)).select_by_visible_text(eValue)
            print(attempt)
        except (StaleElementReferenceException, ElementNotInteractableException, MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException, NoSuchElementException, InvalidElementStateException) :
            if attempt == 10:
                raise
            attempt += 1
```

I call the function like this:

```
    elementName = "FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleYear"
    elementValue = "2015"
    loop_select_keys(elementName,elementValue)

    elementName = "FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleMake"
    elementValue = "HONDA"
    loop_select_keys(elementName,elementValue)

    elementName = "FFQAuto_Vehicle_vehicleModel"
    elementValue = "CIVIC 4D LX"
    loop_select_keys(elementName,elementValue)
```

Comment: what are some of the combinations youve tried?